# Do not work methods FindViewById() and play() and do not work class view in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Do not work methods FindViewById() and play() and do not work class view in Android Studio.
I'm getting this error message from the android studio compiler

```
error: cannot find symbol class view
error: cannot find symbol method FindViewById(int)
error: cannot find symbol method play()
```

It is my code:

```
package com.example.karol.androidappwithsound;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.os.Bundle;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button clk1;
MediaPlayer mdx;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    clk1= (Button) FindViewById(R.id.button4);
    mdx = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.raper);

}


public void clkplay(view v)
{

    mdx.stop();
    mdx = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.raper);
    mdx.play();
}
}
```

Please  help me

Comment: Can you please indicate which line the errors are on?

Comment: I hope u re not trolling us. try View, findViewById and .start()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java, like many programming languages, is case-sensitive:

- The `Activity` method is `findViewById()`, not `FindViewById()`
- The Java class is `View`, not `view`

And there is no `play()` method [on `MediaPlayer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).  You may want [the `start()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#start()).

Answer (score 1):

```
clk1= (Button) FindViewById(R.id.button4);
```

should be `clk1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);` with a lowercase f

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about case-sensitive. Write `findViewById()` instead `FindViewById()` and your button method must be `clkplay(View v)`